# Set preferred task ordering

Tags: tasks, microsoft-project, microsoft-project-2013

In my project, I have (among others) tasks A and B such that there is no dependency between them, and each of them can be carried out by resource R1 or resource R2. All things being equal, it makes more sense to do A before B (especially if both are done by the same resource), but it's not strictly necessary.

Is there a way to capture this relationship between tasks and have Project honour it when levelling? I currently solve this by introducing a start-to-start dependency of B on A if they're done by the same resource. Hower, sometimes I have to re-assign tasks between resources (as new tasks crop up, resources go on unexpected leave and so on), and if I forget to remove these dependencies, they can worsen the planning considerably.

I tried setting the priority of task A higher than task B, but it doesn't seem to have an effect on their relative ordering.

Comment: While this is a specific software question and **is on topic**, you might want to look on http://pm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you'd rather do A before B - why set a Start to Start dependency?  Priority only comes in to play if you use resource leveling - and specifically set the leveling calculation to Priority, Standard.  If you set both tasks with the same predecessor - they will be scheduled to start at the same time, even though there is no relationship.  Consider using notes or setting one of the spare Flag fields to "yes" as a reminder of special circumstances.

Comment: @JulieS I do use levelling, and I would like levelling to honour the preferrence. I can achieve this by setting start-to-start, which means B must not start before A and since they're by the same resource, it must start later. But if I later reassign one of them to a different resource, it messes up further planning.

Comment: Try using priority and creating larger gaps between the priority numbers.  Then use Priority, Standard in the leveling calculation.  You can also quickly view tasks that were leveled because of resource overallocations in the Leveling Gantt.  (Or add the leveling delay field to a task view).  Flag the tasks that were delayed or if you re-assign tasks, run the leveling command again and it will remove any delay that is not necessary.

Comment: @JulieS Thanks for the tips, I will try that on Monday (I have no access to the project before then).

Comment: @JulieS Thanks, combining large gaps with `Priority, Standard` seems to have solved it. If you turn the comment into an answer, I will happily accept it.

Comment: @Angew.  Glad to know the larger gaps worked for you in combination of the different leveling setting.  I have posted the comment as an answer.  Thanks for you feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using priority and creating larger gaps between the priority numbers. Then use Priority, Standard in the leveling calculation. You can also quickly view tasks that were leveled because of resource overallocations in the Leveling Gantt. (Or add the leveling delay field to a task view). Flag the tasks that were delayed or if you re-assign tasks, run the leveling command again and it will remove any delay that is not necessary.